# If $a$ is odd then$(a^2)^n \equiv1$ (mod $2^{n+1}$) for all $n \geq 1$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $a$ is odd then $(a^2)^n \equiv 1 (mod 2^{n+1})$ for all $n \geq 1$

I know it is false statement when I prove it by induction but could you help me give me counterexample show it is false I try many example without helpful

Comment: What do you mean by a^2^n -- $a^{2^n}$?

Comment: Do you mean $a^{(2^n)}$ or $(a^2)^n$?  You had the latter previously.

Comment: I mean the 2 has power also

Comment: But you've reverted it to the former...  Maybe you mean "a^{2^n}"?

Comment: yes i mean like that

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement has oscillated between two forms...

When the problem statement wants $(a^2)^n \not \cong 1 \pmod {2^{n+1}}$, take $a=n=3$.  Then $3^{2 \cdot 3} \cong 9 \pmod{2^4}$.

When the problem statement wants $a^{(2^n)} \not \cong 1 \pmod {2^{n+1}}$, there is no solution.  (I.e., the very large power is always congruent to $1$.)  Why?  We consider Euler's totient (the order of the multiplicative group): $\phi(2^{n+1}) = 2^{n+1}(1-\frac{1}{2}) = 2^n$.  By Euler's theorem, every unit $a$ satisfies $a^{\phi(m)} \cong 1 \pmod{m}$.